# Using Google Tag Manager to track personalised data

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am considering using Google Tag Manager to track abandoned forms. I note that collecting data that "personally identifies an individual (such as a name, email address or billing information)" is against their [Terms of Service](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/analytics/tag-manager/use-policy/).

However, I am whether Google actually enforce this policy, and if so, how?

P.s I not actually looking to implement this - merely curios whether and how it is actually enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enforced unless people write to Google. There are many tracking mistakes on various sites when PII data gets tracked and no one does anything about it for years, even decades. Google doesn't actively check the content of your data to find PII, but it will investigate and take action if people send complains.

Corp lawyers and tracking specialists are usually extremely careful around gathering PII data without explicit consent. Well, maybe gigantic corps would be an exception since they know exactly how to monetize PII.

Anyhow, the real issue here is that you rarely (if ever) want to know what they type for analytics reasons. You want to know what fields they interacted with, how many times they tried to submit the form, what kind of errors they've got before abandoning. That allows for plenty analysis aimed at the form performance improvement.